# Python, disable Windows 7 Visual Effects (under the performance menu)

Tags: python, windows-7, settings, visual-effects

I've looked around, and I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

**The menu is located here:** Right click my computer, properties, advanced system settings, advanced tab, performance -> settings

That works exactly as I hoped. However, there's a few settings I can't seem to find. Here's my list so far, specifically from the list of options in the visual effects menu.

```
//SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION = Animate controls and elements inside windows
//SPI_SETANIMATION = Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
//SPI_SETMENUANIMATION = Fade or slide menus into view
//SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW = Show shadows under mouse pointer
//SPI_SETDROPSHADOW = Show shadows under windows
//SPI_SETCOMBOBOXANIMATION = Slide open combo boxes
//SPI_SETCLEARTYPE = Smooth edges of screen fonts
//SPI_SETLISTBOXSMOOTHSCROLLING = Smooth-scroll list boxes
//SPI_SETUIEFFECTS = A whole bunch of settings
```

**Still missing these ones**

```
//Animations in the taskbar and Start Menu
//Show translucent selection rectangle
//Show window content while dragging
//Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
//Use visual styles on windows and buttons
```

Has anyone managed to figure out where the remaining settings can be enabled / disabled from? Perhaps I missed a value?

BTW: I'm setting them like this in Python

```
windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETLISTBOXSMOOTHSCROLLING, 0, cBoolTrue, 0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot SPI_SETTOOLTIPANIMATION = Fade or slide tooltips into view

Comment: SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS = Show window content while dragging

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not an actual good answer I'm providing here, but this can be slightly helpful.

The things you want to change can be controlled through registry, you need these values:

```
//Animations in the taskbar and Start Menu              | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced::TaskbarAnimations
//Show translucent selection rectangle                  | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced::ListviewAlphaSelect
//Show window cntents while dragging                    | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop::DragFullWindows
//Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop       | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced::ListviewShadow
//Use visual styles on windows and buttons              | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager::ThemeActive
```

However, this is not the best solution, also restart is required.

---

What else to mention, you are wrong, about some things.

- `SPI_SETCLEARTYPE` is not for font smoothing. For that purpose you have to use `SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING` and `SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE`.
- `SPI_SETUIEFFECTS` - you say it is bunch of settings and you are right. However, you should get/set all of these individually and `SystemParametersInfo` allows to access all of them individually.